# kubectl exec returns unexcepted error messages?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I am currently trying to execute a simple bash command onto my kubernetes pod but seem to be getting some errors which does not make sense.

If I exec into the docker container an run the command plain

```
I have no name!@kafka-0:/tmp$ if [ $(comm -13 <(sort selectedTopics) <(sort topics.sh) | wc -l) -gt 0 ];  then  echo "hello"; fi
```

I get Hello as output.

But if execute the same from the outside as

```
kubectl exec --namespace default kafka-0 -c kafka -- bash -c "if [ $(comm -13 </tmp/selectedTopics </tmp/topics.sh| wc -l) -gt 0 ];  then  echo topic does not exist && exit 1; fi"
```

Then I get an error message stating that  `/tmp/topics.sh: No such file or directory`

event though I able to do this

```
kubectl exec --namespace $namespace kafka-0 -c kafka -- bash -c "cat /tmp/topics.sh"
```

why does kubectl `exec` causing me problems?

Comment: Can you provide the image you are using for your container?

Comment: should be the latest  @guzmonne `helm upgrade kafka bitnami/kafka --install`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
 kubectl ... "$(cmd)"
```

`cmd` is executed on the local host to create the string that is used as the argument to `kubectl`.  In other words, you are executing `comm -13 </tmp/selectedTopics </tmp/topics.sh| wc -l` on the local host, and not in the pod.

You should use single quotes if you want to avoid expanding locally:

```
kubectl exec --namespace default kafka-0 -c kafka -- bash -c 'if comm -13 </tmp/topics.sh grep -q . ;  then  echo topic does not exist >&2 && exit 1; fi'
```